# Creating time series with loops and populating them with values

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, time

I have a data frame, where each row represents a part of the time series.

I need to create a total time series that stretches over several years, for up to several hundred units.

So, each row sets a value for a certain period and then it needs to resume to the max given values (given by maks).

See example here:

Code:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

# My data for 3 units
df <- structure(list(Unit = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), Limit = c(850L, 
655L, 500L, 1000L, 100L, 75L, 0L, 600L, 635L), Max = c(1310L, 
1310L, 1310L, 1300L, 1300L, 1300L, 915L, 915L, 915L), startDate = structure(c(1483250400, 
1430481600, 1546286400, 1421280000, 1498813200, 1546300800, 1420869600, 
1527876000, 1463097600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
endDate = structure(c(1496275200, 1451520000, 1609459200, 
1426431600, 1527811200, 1577836800, 1433170800, 1546383600, 
1464807600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")


# Doing a loop to create time series for each row
d <- NULL

for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  d <- rbind(d, data.frame(Date = seq.POSIXt(from = df$startDate[i], to = df$endDate[i], by = "hour"), 
                           value = df$Limit[i], 
                           unit = df$Unit[i]))

}

# Spread it out to a nice data frame
d <- spread(d, unit, value = value)

# Left join on a global time series
globalStart <- as.POSIXct("2015-01-01 00:00:00", tz = "UTC")
globalEnd <- as.POSIXct("2021-12-01 00:00:00", tz = "UTC")

dfResult <- data.frame(Date = seq.POSIXt(from = globalStart, to = globalEnd, by = "hour"))

# Now join it together
dfResult <- left_join(dfResult, d, by = "Date")

# Add values to fill out NA with max
maks <- c(915, 1315, 900)

dfResult[is.na(dfResult[, 2]), 2] <- maks[1]
dfResult[is.na(dfResult[, 3]), 3] <- maks[2]
dfResult[is.na(dfResult[, 4]), 4] <- maks[3]

# Final result
dfResult
```

My problem is this takes around 35 minutes with my dataset, and this is on just 58 units, potentially I need to do it for thousand of units - and I need to speed this up drastically.

Comment: did you try both methods to see what what method was fastest?

Comment: Ya, I have a preference for base R ;)

Comment: data.table could also be done with: setDT(df)[ , list(Unit = Unit, Limit = Limit, Max = Max, Date = seq(startDate, endDate, by = "hour")), by = 1:nrow(df)]

Comment: Yes I'm aware there are many ways to do it. Just curious as to what was fastest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to replace your loop with this code:

```
# creates date list:
dateList <- lapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) {
  seq.POSIXt(df$startDate[x], df$endDate[x], by = "hour")
  })
llengths <- lengths(dateList) # lengths of date vectors
# combine everything together:
d <- data.frame(Date = do.call("c", dateList),
                value = rep(df$Limit, llengths),
                unit = rep(df$Unit, llengths))
```

The main problem of your code is the usage of `rbind`. Try avoiding it, particularly in loops.

Answer (score 1):

could try minimising the number of steps and using `data.table`.

Instead of expanding the original data.frame, you can use `foverlaps()` to join to the whole timeline and then use `dcast()` to spread. Then just update by reference the NA values.

```
library(data.table)

df <- structure(list(Unit = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"),
                     Limit = c(850L, 655L, 500L, 1000L, 100L, 75L, 0L, 600L, 635L), Max = c(1310L, 1310L, 1310L, 1300L, 1300L, 1300L, 915L, 915L, 915L),
                     startDate = structure(c(1483250400, 1430481600, 1546286400, 1421280000, 1498813200, 1546300800, 1420869600, 1527876000, 1463097600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
                     endDate = structure(c(1496275200, 1451520000, 1609459200, 1426431600, 1527811200, 1577836800, 1433170800, 1546383600, 1464807600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")),
                row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")

# use data.table with key
dataset <- as.data.table(df)
setkey(dataset, "startDate", "endDate")

# start - end for whole timeline
globalStart <- as.POSIXct("2015-01-01 00:00:00", tz = "UTC")
globalEnd <- as.POSIXct("2021-12-01 00:00:00", tz = "UTC")

# data.table of start and end for each period, used with `foverlaps()`
timeline_dt <- data.table(Dttm = seq.POSIXt(globalStart, globalEnd, "hour"),
                          endDate = seq.POSIXt(globalStart, globalEnd, "hour") + 3599L)
# not required to be keyed but may as well
setkey(timeline_dt, "Dttm", "endDate")

# join by period overlapping, retain columns of interest
dataset_result <- foverlaps(timeline_dt, dataset)[, .(Dttm, Unit, Limit)]
# same as spread, drop NA column
dataset_result <- dcast(dataset_result, Dttm ~ Unit, value.var = "Limit")[, -"NA"]

# iterate over maks, and update by reference 
# i + 1L because we skip first column which is Dttm
maks <- c(915, 1315, 900)
for (i in seq_along(maks)) {
  set(x = dataset_result,
      i = which(is.na(dataset_result[[i+1L]])),
      j = i+1L,
      value = maks[i])
}
```